# How send a message with a Discord Bot in C#?

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I'm trying to understand how should I send a message with Discord Bot into my channel without any event or command sent by me?

The result that I would like to achieve is that through a timer bot you send a message in the chat every minute.

If you can explain it to me with some examples, I would be very grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to send messages into channels without using commands. In essence, you are asking how to send messages from a class that does not inherit from `ModuleBase`.

This requires you to use Dependency Injection to inject your `DiscordSocketClient` into the class you want to send messages from.

You can learn more about Dependency Injection (because it is a large topic) in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and in the [example bot](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/tree/dev/samples/02_commands_framework) provided by Discord.Net (assuming you are using this library).

The simple solution is shown below.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    public MyClass(DiscordSocketClient client) => client = client 

    public async Task SendMessageToChannel(ulong channelId, string message)
    {
        SocketChannel channel = _client.GetChannel(channelId);
        await (channel as IMessageChannel).SendMessageAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Ideally you should also create an interface called `IMyClass` and have `MyClass` implement it. This way, you can effectively configure the methods of `MyClass` as a service too.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation
I see that anyone who creates a bot uses "Console App", but can't do it with "Windows Form App"?

Because I'm trying to create a bot that uses the Form app to perform calculations, etc. And send me this data in the Discord chat, but it's not clear to me if it's actually possible and how to do it. If you have any examples, I would be very grateful to you.